# Follow a file with row and column

Tags: evil, find-file

How to make `g f` and/or `find-file-at-point` resolve file correctly in this format (gcc output)

```
main.c:123:31: ....
```

Comment: For those who do no evil, what does `g f` do? Are these errors/warnings? Are you running gcc with `M-x compile`? If so, does ``C-x ` `` (bound to `next-error`) do what you want?

Comment: `g f` does `find-file-at-point` ultimately. I run gcc in shell-mode

Comment: AFAICT, `ffap` does not grok that format at all. I would try running it with `M-x compile` - for a simple program, `foo.c` you don't have to write a Makefile at all: when you are prompted for the command to run, say `make foo`. You can then use `next-error` or just click on the file:line:col specification and you are there. The command is remembered, so you can iterate very quickly.